# android - jsonArray.length() returning null even after getting JSON output from localhost

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, arrays

This is my simple android activity pulling JSON data from my localhost

```
public class JSONtest extends ActionBarActivity {

private ProgressDialog dialog;

String message3;
String[] items;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jsontest);

    String localhost = "http://10.0.2.2/example/json/notification.php";
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("Downloading Recent Notifications. Please wait...");
    new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute(localhost);
}

private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(JSONtest.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Downloading Recent Notifications. Please wait . . .");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String...urls)
    {
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            items = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            id_list = new String[jsonArray.length()];

            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                message3 = "SUBJECT : " + jobj.getString("subject") + "\n\n" + 
                        "TIME : " + jobj.getString("time");

                items[i] = message3;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv.setText("Done! Click to view Notifications. ");
    }
}

public void helpMe(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(JSONtest.this, Temp.class);
    i.putExtra("items", items);
    startActivity(i);
}

public String readJSONFeed(String URL)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(URL);
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(hg);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == 200)
        {
            HttpEntity en = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = en.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download File");
        }
    }
    catch(ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

My JSON output from my PHP script is

```
[{"subject":"Subject One","time":"2:00pm"},{"subject":"Subject Two","time":"2:30pm"}]
```

But my code isn't working. So I tried outputting the `result` in `TextView` in `onPostExecute(String result)` and this gives me the JSON output as it is, as above. Meaning my app receives the JSON output. But my `jsonArray.length()` returns `null`. What is wrong in my code? 
 Please Help.

the Log says

```
11-05 13:05:31.523: W/EGL_emulation(1909): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-05 13:05:32.563: W/EGL_emulation(1909): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-05 13:05:32.643: W/EGL_emulation(1909): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"time":"2:00pm","subject":"Subject One"},{"time":"2:30pm","subject":"Subject Two"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at com.onclaveinc.ioexception.JSONtest$ReadJSONFeedTask.onPostExecute(JSONtest.java:70)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at com.onclaveinc.ioexception.JSONtest$ReadJSONFeedTask.onPostExecute(JSONtest.java:1)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-05 13:05:32.673: W/System.err(1909):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure your jsonArray object is not null?

Comment: the `result` in `onPostExecute(String result)` shows me the full JSON data meaning my app is getting the JSON data. Should that not mean that my jsonArray object is not `null`? I am not sure.

Comment: Then you have to debug it and check if it is null or not. Or verify if jsonArray.isEmpty().

Comment: I tried to do `tv.setText(Integer.toString(jsonArray.length()))` where `tv` is a `TextView` and that shows me `null` in the `TextView`  on running the app. Does it not mean that my `jsonArray` is empty. But why would that be empty when it is getting the JSON output? I have no clue. @joao2fast4u

Comment: That confirms that your JSONArray is null. What about your result value? Did you check its value on your code?

Comment: Yes, I did. And it returns me the JSON encoded output.
`[{"subject":"Subject One","time":"2:00pm"},{"subject":"Subject Two","time":"2:30pm"}]` So the result does get the required JSON output. And that is passed to the JSONArray constructor.

Comment: I tried to do `I tried to do tv.setText(result)`.Gives me the JSON output on screen.

Comment: Are you using org.json.JSONArray class?

Comment: Yes. `import org.json.JSONArray`. I use this.

Comment: Try this on onPostExecute(result): `result = "[{\"subject\":\"Subject One\",\"time\":\"2:00pm\"},{\"subject\":\"Subject Two\",\"time\":\"2:30pm\"}]";` , before JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

Comment: Is your JSONArray constructor receiving a String?

Comment: `result` is `String` in the `onPostExecute()` and constructor is receiving this `result`. And i also tried the result you gave me, 
`result = "[{\"subject\":\"Subject One\",\"time\":\"2:00pm\"},{\"subject\":\"Subject Two\",\"time\":\"2:30pm\"}]";` the problem persists. That means it cannot handle any JSON data. But why?

Comment: That is strange indeed. Try to do JSONObject jsonArray = new JSONObject(result); instead.

Comment: Ok, but then what do I do to the line `JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);` because after changing `JSONArray` to `JSONObject` this line gives error.

Comment: It is supposed to do so. What is the Exception?

Comment: No it is not giving an exception, it is giving an error `The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Comment: int? But isn't `result` a String?

Comment: Yes, but that line is not having any errors. Look at my code, the part inside the `for loop` has a `JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);` to take in each JSON array element separately, it is giving me this error here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64343/discussion-between-joao2fast4u-and-sajib-acharya).

Comment: What is id_list? I tried every thing even for loop is working here.

What does e.printStackTrace(); says? Give us that log.

Comment: Please recheck, I have  added the log when the activity  tries to get the JSON data. and `id_list` is just a  String array that I am not using.  @Chitrang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you should use `JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);` instead,  when iterating over your `JSONArray`. You also had to check when your `JsonObject` was null before you add it to your `items` `String []`. I also suggested that you added a catch on your `try catch` block so you can figure out when you have a `JSONException`.

Comment: Yes, and thank you so much  for the time and effort you have put towards my problem. :)